# CSS linear gradient animation doesn't work in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, animation, linear-gradients, keyframe

currently Im working on a website for a school project. The site has to run on the newer browsers.

I want to have an animation, which goes from middle to fill the box. The separating lines next to it should be animated to. I had some troubles using height, so I am using gradients with hard cuts to accomplish this.
It works on Edge, Chrome and IE10(!), but not on Firefox.

```
@keyframes expandtwo {
    from {
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, 
        rgba(255,143,0,0) 40%, 
        rgba(255,143,0,1) 40%,
        rgba(255,143,0,1) 60%,
        rgba(255,143,0,0) 60%);
    }
    to {
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, 
        rgba(255,143,0,0) 0%, 
        rgba(255,143,0,1) 0%,
        rgba(255,143,0,1) 100%,
        rgba(255,143,0,0) 100%);
    }
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/418wwn95/1/

I saved you from Jquery to realize the seperating lines and the full animation (120 lines, because chrome is too dumb to do it by himself) and minimized it to start and end point. Still shows the problem.

Comment: `background-image` is not animatable.

Comment: you can use background-size https://jsfiddle.net/418wwn95/2/